# Convert String to Uri

Tags: java, android, string, uri

How can I convert a String to a Uri in Java (Android)? i.e.:

```
String myUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

**myUri = ???;**

Answer (score 595, accepted):

You can use the `parse` static method from `Uri`

```
//...
import android.net.Uri;
//...

Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but i have a problem with it. First Uri need to be changed to URI(if it is from java.net package). Second it does not have the "parse" constructor. Do you have any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: There is a `Uri` class with a `parse` method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html . There is also a `URI` class http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html without a `parse` method. So the right class to use is `Uri`. Make sure you have the correct import

Comment: @ccheneson Why should Uri be more correct then URI? With URI you can just use the `create` method. It's as simple to use as Uri. So what benefit do you have from Uri?

Comment: That is right. Wrong imports are one of my annoying problems too.

Comment: So it is that simple  :)

Answer (score 55):

I am just using the `java.net` **package**.
Here you can do the following:

```
...
import java.net.URI;
...

String myUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com";
URI myURI = new URI(myUrl);
```

Answer (score 15):

If you are using **Kotlin** and Kotlin android extensions, then there is a beautiful way of doing this.

```
val uri = myUriString.toUri()
```

To add Kotlin extensions (**KTX**) to your project add the following to your app module's build.gradle

```
  repositories {
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-rc01'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can parse a String to a Uri by using **[Uri.parse()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String))** as shown below:

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

The following is an example of how you can use your newly created Uri in an implicit intent. To be viewed in a browser on the users phone.

```
// Creates a new Implicit Intent, passing in our Uri as the second paramater.
Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, myUri);

// Checks to see if there is an Activity capable of handling the intent
if (webIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
    startActivity(webIntent);
}
```

**NB:** There is a difference between Androids **[URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html)** and **[Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)**.

Answer (score 6):

```
import java.net.URI;
```

Below also works for me :

```
URI uri = URI.create("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

OR

```
URI uri = new URI("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

Java's parser in `java.net.URI` is going to fail if the URI isn't fully encoded to its standards. For example, try to parse: `http://www.google.com/search?q=cat|dog`. An exception will be thrown for the vertical bar.

[urllib](https://github.com/EricEdens/urllib) makes it easy to convert a string to a `java.net.URI`. It will pre-process and escape the URL.

```
assertEquals("http://www.google.com/search?q=cat%7Cdog",
    Urls.createURI("http://www.google.com/search?q=cat|dog").toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this too

for http

```
var response = await http.get(Uri.http("192.168.100.91", "/api/fetch.php"));
```

or

for https

```
var response = await http.get(Uri.https("192.168.100.91", "/api/fetch.php"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you going to do with the URI?

If you're just going to use it with an HttpGet for example, you can just use the string directly when creating the HttpGet instance.

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: But for example `android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI` won't — so it is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: actually this does not answer the question