# How to convert a String to an android.net.Uri

Tags: android, string, uri

Question:
I have found that `java.net.URI` has a create(String uri) option but the `android.net.uri` does not.

More specifically:
I am trying to grab the output of RingtoneManager's `RingtonePicker` and set it as the default ringtone with `SetActualDefaultRingtoneUri`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra( RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE
                     ,RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

intent.putExtra( RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE
                     , "Select Tone For Rainy Days");

startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this
                     ,RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE
                     ,RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
```

The problem is that `RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI` returns a string not a URI.
There might be a better way than to convert the string to a URI. I cannot find a reason why java.net.URI can do it and android.net.Uri can't.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: See this if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487389/java-convert-string-to-uri/3487413#3487413

Answer (score 36):

I guess you want to use the `parse` method from the `android.net.uri` class. It returns a URi for the supplied encoded string.

[android.net.uri parse()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String))

Comment: Thanks guys but I found my solution.

Comment: Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
 
 RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this,RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,uri);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, but this is how I ended up making it work

```
Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this,RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,uri);
```