# Android Push Notification - Parsing JSON Notification tag name to get raw file (Resource Id or Uri)

Tags: android, json, push-notification, android-notifications

I am getting notification from `GCM` in onMessage() method as intent extraData in `json` string given below:-

```
"data": { "message":"Welcome Message","sound_file":"sound1.mp3"}
```

And I have same file name `sound1.mp3` in my `res/raw/sound1.mp3` which i need to assign in `Notification.Sound`. So is there any mechanism by which I can convert `String` to `ResourceId` or access the `ResourceId` through `Uri` to assign in `Notification.Sound`.

I want to do this because there will be multiple files and any random `sound_file` name can come in notification message.

> Note:- I can use `if else` to check `sound_file` with my files stored in
>   `raw` folder that i have already implemented. But i just want to know is that can be done what i have asked???

Comment: for String to Uri : [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487389/convert-string-to-uri)

Comment: Uri of RecsourceID not String to Uri

Comment: then look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896223/how-to-get-an-uri-of-an-image-resource-in-android) , I think the combination might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
int resourceId = context.getResources("sound1.mp3", "raw", context.getPackageName());
Uri resourceUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + resourceId);
```