# How to go from a String of URI Array to a actual URI Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, uri, data-conversion

```
String arr = "[ab, cd, ef]"
URI [] arr2 =arr.toURI()
```

I need the string representation of the uri array to go to an actual uri list, should i need to convert to a string array prior to going to a uri array?
 the tricky part is the list conversion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to Uri](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487389/convert-string-to-uri)

Comment: its not, I can get it to go to a URI thats simple making it an array is what i need... from a sting representation.