# How do I convert String to URI

Tags: java, methods, import, uri, spotify

I need a parameter for the setRedirectUri method but it only takes URI. Is there a way to convert String into URI?

```
import com.wrapper.spotify.*;
import java.net.URI;

public class Music {

    private String id;
    private String secret;

    public void authenticate(String id, String secret)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.secret = secret;
        URI myAccount = new URI("<URI>");
        SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi.Builder()
                .setClientId(this.id)
                .setClientSecret(this.secret)
                .setRedirectUri(myAccount)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: `java.net.URI` has a constructor which accepts just a String. `new URI(myString);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert String to Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487389/convert-string-to-uri)

Comment: i've tried that and the constructor gives this error "Unhandled exception type URISyntaxException" am i missing some syntax?

Comment: @NovaG35 Well, try to wrap those lines with a try catch block or add throws URISyntaxException to your method

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
        SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi.Builder()
                .setClientId(this.id)
                .setClientSecret(this.secret)
                .setRedirectUri(
                     new java.net.URI("<your URI>"))
                .build();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html?is-external=true